# Advancing Stage in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code, I'm relatively new to JavaScript, so can anyone tell me why it isn't advancing to stage 1 + show me how it's done?

```
var textContainer = '#text';
var inputLine = 'input';

var username = null;
var stage = 0;

$(function(){
        if(0 == stage){
            $(function(){
                $(textContainer).text('What is your name?');
                $(inputLine).focus();
                $(inputLine).keypress(function(e){
                    if (e.keyCode == 13 && !e.shiftKey) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        username = $(this).val();
                        $(this).val('');
                        stage = 1;
                    }
                });
            });
        }
        if(1 == stage){
            $(textContainer).text('Hi there, ' + username + '.');
        }
    });
```

Comment: Where's the code you're calling this function?

Comment: `$(function(){` is shorthand for `$(document).ready()`.

Comment: I wanted to advance to the next if statement (if(1 == stage))

Comment: Sorry that it didn't make it clear. I am basically building a text based adventure game and will later be storing which stage the user is on so they can resume later on, that's why I was using stages.

Answer (score 1):

What you have there doesn't make much sense, so I'm guessing this is what you're trying to do :

```
$(function(){
     var textContainer = $('#text'),
         inputLine = $('input');

     textContainer.text('What is your name?');
     inputLine.focus().on('keyup', function(e){
        if (e.which === 13) {
            e.preventDefault();
            textContainer.text('Hi there, ' + this.value + '.');
            this.value = "";
        }
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/cNqbV/1/)

There is no way `stage` could be anything other than zero right after it's set to zero?
What happens inside the event handler, happens "later", so checking `stage` after the event handler still gives you ... wait for it .... zero ?